# Rotating text keeps the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to rotate a text and shrink to a new width to fit in container, but when I do, the block keeps the width ruining my plans, I'm in trouble with this. The code I'm trying to use is:

```
.text90 {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Look this in full page to see my problem:

```css
/** RESET PAGE DOWNHERE **/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400i,700,700i|Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro:400,900");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul, li, ol, a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1270px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #252525;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Droid Serif", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
  font-family: "Droid Serif", serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #898989;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
/** RESET PAGE UPHERE **/

.content {
  padding: 50px 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.text90 {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header container"></div>
<div class="content container">
  <h2 class="text90">Title Example</h2>
  <div class="insideContent">
    <h3>Other Title Example</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae cum qui error incidunt animi, aliquid fugit quae! Quia necessitatibus dolore temporibus unde voluptas optio, beatae eos neque ipsum, suscipit at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam numquam perferendis mollitia temporibus quidem, id molestias distinctio ex magnam magni, voluptatum exercitationem esse quibusdam nostrum nobis libero excepturi cupiditate qui? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat expedita odit minus nulla quas, consequuntur repellendus voluptatem, ratione, libero cupiditate voluptas quod facilis nisi ipsum alias. Dolorum reprehenderit quod aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus nisi odio delectus, illum incidunt atque iste, eveniet velit dicta quasi saepe, quibusdam accusantium excepturi sit ipsum distinctio dolore obcaecati soluta!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer container"></div>
```

Like you can see, the width of H2 piratically destroys all the next side text, how can I fix this? I've already tried all my knowledge... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `writing-mode: vertical-lr;`. But this will start the text from top to bottom so it needs to re-rotate to `180deg`.

```css
/** RESET PAGE DOWNHERE **/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400i,700,700i|Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro:400,900");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul, li, ol, a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1270px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #252525;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Droid Serif", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
  font-family: "Droid Serif", serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #898989;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
/** RESET PAGE UPHERE **/

.content {
  padding: 50px 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.text90 {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -ms-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -o-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="header container"></div>
<div class="content container">
  <h2 class="text90">Title Example</h2>
  <div class="insideContent">
    <h3>Other Title Example</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae cum qui error incidunt animi, aliquid fugit quae! Quia necessitatibus dolore temporibus unde voluptas optio, beatae eos neque ipsum, suscipit at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam numquam perferendis mollitia temporibus quidem, id molestias distinctio ex magnam magni, voluptatum exercitationem esse quibusdam nostrum nobis libero excepturi cupiditate qui? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat expedita odit minus nulla quas, consequuntur repellendus voluptatem, ratione, libero cupiditate voluptas quod facilis nisi ipsum alias. Dolorum reprehenderit quod aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus nisi odio delectus, illum incidunt atque iste, eveniet velit dicta quasi saepe, quibusdam accusantium excepturi sit ipsum distinctio dolore obcaecati soluta!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer container"></div>
```